# .flip-button-icon - CSS - Make it shake upon page load infinte

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS / Divi but did Google and spend the last 2+ hours trying to do it... so give me some slack please. =)

Happy to tip the generous helper for their time, probably save me half a day figuring it out...

CTA button has this icon >> which I would love for it to shake upon page load. (Happy for it to keep shacking upon mouse hover)

Current code (which work's ok upon hover but not as fancy)

```
.flip-button-icon:hover:after 
{
  transition: transform 1000ms;
}
.flip-button-icon:hover:after 
{
  transform: translate(5px);
}
```

//Tried to make this work but failed..

```
    0% { transform: translate(0px); }
   25% { transform: translate(5px); }
   50% { transform: translate(0px); }
   75% { transform: translate(5px); }
  100% { transform: translate(0px); }
```

Anyhow you get the idea.... lol

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example I just created: (found a nice shake animatoin in the web)

```css
.flip-button-icon:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-button-icon" style="background-color:#f00;height:20px;width:20px;"></div>
```

If you want your button to shake on page load you will have to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, I'd recommend familiarising yourself with [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) to get a good general understanding on this area.

Anyway, I've used your own keyframes to create the following, which will shake on page load. As you wanted the on-load animation to be infinite, I've removed the hover animation.

Edit: amended code to isolate the button's inner text, and only animate that. You can quickly check it out here: https://codepen.io/Cursa/pen/qBdbjaX

```html
<button>
  <div class="shakyText">>></div>
</button>
```

```css
.shakyText
{
  animation: shake 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: translate(0px); }
  25% { transform: translate(5px); }
  50% { transform: translate(0px); }
  75% { transform: translate(5px); }
  100% { transform: translate(0px); }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cursa, thank you. That works almost perfectly, better than mine. It does shake the whole button instead of just the icon though...? That maybe a DIVI thing gone wrong or something gone bad with my button. I will try it again on a new button a bit later tonight... either way I would be happy with that if that's the best I can do. Thank you =)

Comment: Hey Luis! Ah, I get you now -- see my edited answer which should achieve what you're looking for. To isolate and solely animate the text of the button I've had to make it a child element of the outer button.

Comment: Thank you guys. Much appreciated. This should help other newbies as well. Its been a long time since I did Java, you can imagine the noob feeling rehashing everything.